# kendo listview with custom edit template - not able to change model values

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo listview with custom edit template,

And this is the list view Code

```
var warrantyContact_listview = $("#warrantyContact_listview").kendoListView({
        autoBind: false,
        dataSource: dataSource,
        template: kendo.template($("#warrantyContact_listview_template").html()),
        editTemplate: kendo.template($("#warrantyContact_editview_template").html())
    }).data("kendoListView");
```

And here is the edit template Code

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="warrantyContact_editview_template">
    <div id="con_editview">        
    <dd>
    <dt>Person</dt>
    <input type="text" 
    data-role = "autocomplete" 
    data-source = "some_datasource" 
    data-text-field = "fname"  
    data-value-field = "bid"
    class="k-textbox" 
    data-bind="value:some_value" 
    name="builder" 
    required = "required"
    validationMessage = "required"  
    id="builder"/>
    <span data-for="some_value" class="k-invalid-msg"></span>
    </dd><br clear="all"/>                       

    <dt>City</dt>
    <dd>
    <input type="text" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:city" name="city" required = "required" validationMessage = "required" />
    <span data-for="city" class="k-invalid-msg"></span>
    </dd><br clear="all"/>

    <dt>State</dt>
    <dd>
    <input type="text" name = "state" class="k-textbox"  data-bind = "value:state" data-value-field="abbrev" data-text-field="abbrev" data-min-length="1" data-source="states_datasource" data-role="autocomplete" required = "required" validationMessage = "required" />
    <span data-for="state" class="k-invalid-msg"></span>
    </dd><br clear="all"/>

    <dt>Zip</dt>
    <dd>
    <input type="text" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:zip" name="zip" required = "required" validationMessage = "required" />
    <span data-for="zip" class="k-invalid-msg"></span>
    </dd><br clear="all"/>

    </dl>
    </div>
</script>
```

Here is the scenario

When the listview enters into the edit mode, I would fill in in the first field "Person" which is an auto complete.

Based on what value I select for the Autocomplete "Person", I would like to assign its corresponding values to the city, state and zip. I am able to assign the values successfully. ( which I do with jquery ajax in the select event of the Person Auto complete)

But, when I call the `$("#warrantyContact_listview").data("kendoListView").save();`

When I check the firebug console,

those changed values city, state and zip are not been passed to the server side.

What I am missing here?

Do I have to change the binding of values in the template here?

I tried to change the values in the parameter map function, but, it did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you setting the values in the inputs ? I set the value in the model and its set but the inputs are still empty. Can you share the code snippet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that when you change the values, you don't use the [set() method of the ObservableObject](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/model#methods-set) in dataSource, so the kendo dataSource doesn't know that the fields of the observable are modified. 
So on save() ( which calls sync() for the dataSource ) it doesn't see anything new, and it doesn't update anything.

Check manually your datasource, change something with set() and use save() to see if it's saved.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem, :)

Comment: You should be in edit mode as well (ie. grid.edit(row)). It is possible that one could run into this problem because they have manually edited values based on some outside condition while not in edit mode and tried to save. The editable property of the grid will be undefined and the save will not do anything.